# Saved Search criteria/results seem to have a different naming scheme from everything else

Tags: netsuite

I'm trying to find a resource or explanation for how to determine how a field will display in the criteria or results dropdown of a saved search. For instance, in the results I would like to see the PO# field (fieldId:otherrefnum). But when looking through the drop down, I see neither of these as options. This has been a serious source of frustration for me with many other fields, I'd like to find a definitive way to avoid wasting time on this in the future.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of contributing factors to this.

- The field names you see on forms may have been re-labeled by form customizations
- Netsuite normalizes transaction searches to which leads to some (IMO) odd column name re-use.
- A lot of old fields or fields tied to functionality (e.g. transaction status fields) don't follow the regular pattern of numeric id and text name.

The [records browser](https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2022_1/script/record/transaction.html) helps quite a bit. You can search here and see that `otherrefnum` is named 'PO/Check Number' in the search editor. (An example of field name normalizing referred to above)

If you look at transaction you'll see it is just search filters and columns. If you compare to [Sales Order](https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2022_1/script/record/salesorder.html) you'll see something perhaps more familiar in terms of fields.

Even armed with the records browser experience is still needed. e.g.

A sales order has an `items` sublist and one of its fields is `itemtype`. In order to get that value in a search you need to select Item fields and then choose Type.  A Sales Order's `items.description` column becomes the line level `memo` field in search results.

Hope this helps